# What happens to directory entry when a file is renamed

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext3, ext2, lustre

What exactly happens to the directory entry when a file is renamed?
Is it that the entry of the oldfile is flushed and the newfile is replaced at it's place or a completely new entry is made at the end of the directory entry?

Comment: Please clarify about which filesystem you are talking. For example not every filesystem stores directory entries in a list.

Comment: I am talking about ext4. But also would like to know about ext2, ext3 filesystems.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? It's an internal detail of the filesystem implementation of it's directory structure not observable from the outside. If you care about the internals, look at the code. If you care about observable properties (like performance), ask specific question about them.

Comment: Your question looks a bit like you are asking about dentries that are kept by VFS. But comments say you mean Ext4 internals.